# list index out of range

Tags: python

Почему строка с индексом k уходит за пределы списка в цикле?

```
введите сюда код

with open('avtor.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
avt = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar=',')
avtor =list(avt)
count_1 = [row for row in avtor]
k = 0
csvfile.close()

with open('avtorsaaaa.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
ava = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar=',')
avtors=list(ava)
count_2 = [row for row in avtors]
l = 0

row_1 = len(avtors)
while l<row_1:
    for avtor [k] in avtors [l]:
        if avtor [k] in avtors [l]:
            vstrech = vstrech+1
            l=l+1
        elif avtor not in avtors:
            l=l+1
        elif count_2 != ',':
            k=k+1
        elif count_1 != ',':
            l = l + 1
        else:
            break
```

k и l номера строк в списке

Comment: Переменные k и l в этом примере не существуют, покажите более полный код

Comment: Покажите весь код или нам гадать что у вас там случилось?)

Comment: отредактировал)